# 日本に居るのにサンドボックス環境にて定期購読課金すると、注文日時がタイムゾーンPDT形式になる

Tags: android, アプリ内課金

リファレンスサイトなどを見てみると、定期購読課金は、

月額課金の場合、　「購入日の翌月同日に課金される」
年額課金の場合、「購入日の翌年同日に課金される」とありますが、
ここでいう「日」とは、タイムゾーン的には何でしょうか？(PST/PDT/JST/UTC)

現在調査してみてわかったことですが、
サンドボックス環境では、メール通知でくる購入レシートを見る限り、
定期購読課金の場合、注文日時がPDT形式で
アプリ内課金の場合、注文日時がJST形式でした。

定期購読課金の場合もJSTにならないのはなぜでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

------検証環境

Galaxy S5 Active OS5.0

端末設定：

言語・地域：日本

---

Comment: Google Playの課金制度についてのトピックはプログラミングとはほとんど関係のない質問のように思われます（プログラムによって、表示状態が変更できるといった話でしたら別です）。

Comment: hataさん。コメントいただきありがとうございます。
おっしゃる通り、プログラミングとは別の 質問になってしまい失礼いたしました。
どこに問い合わせてよいかわからず、こちらで質問投げてしまった次第です。

Comment: Andoさん、[Google プロダクトフォーラム](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-ja)が適切だと思われます。

Comment: 情報提供ありがとうございます。
Google プロダクトフォーラムという存在初めて知りました。
早速質問投げてみたいと思います。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: Google プロダクトフォーラムに質問投げました。
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-ja/RNRFjoPpzsQ;context-place=forum/play-ja